# Auto-Saving in Emacs not working properly when directory specified

Tags: emacs, elisp, autosave, emacs24

I'm trying to set autosave to use a directory in ./emacs.d/autosaves. I previously used the two commented out lines below and currently tried the other function I found on the web. Really all I want is the autosaves to not be stored in the same directory. It does this in

```
(defvar autosave-dir
 (concat "/home/" (user-login-name) "/.emacs.d/autosaves/"))
(make-directory autosave-dir t)
(defun auto-save-file-name-p (filename)
  (string-match "^#.*#$" (file-name-nondirectory filename)))
(defun make-auto-save-file-name ()
  (concat autosave-dir
   (if buffer-file-name
      (concat "#" (file-name-nondirectory buffer-file-name) "#")
    (expand-file-name
     (concat "#%" (buffer-name) "#")))))
;; (setq auto-save-file-name-transforms
;;       `(("#.*#" ,"~/.emacs.d/backups/" t)))
```

or can I set autosave to put a #notes.org# at the beginning and end of the file because currently has the format .#notes.org.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's about locking the file. For more information, read:

```
(info "(emacs) Interlocking")
```

Basically no way around it unless perform a minor rewrite and compile your own emacs source from what I had read.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is just (assuming that the directory referred to by `autosave-dir` exists that is):

```
(setq auto-save-file-name-transforms
      `((".*" ,autosave-dir t)))
```

Personally I favour the use the standard *tmp* directory for autosaves:

```
(setq auto-save-file-name-transforms
      `((".*" ,temporary-file-directory t)))
```

Comment: That's what I used to have but commented it out or something similar. It still saves in the current directory. Then if I exit without saving for example it will copy it over to that directory but initially is created in the current directory with .# before the filename.

Comment: That's very odd - I've been using this for quite a while and it certainly works on Emacs 24.1.

Comment: Yeah it used to work properly not sure what happened. Thought it might have been org-mode but it does it in every mode. Even if I reset it in the scratch buffer while running it still doesn't work properly. I am not sure what is going on. I have emacs 24.1 on one machine and emacs 23.3 on another. Neither does it work properly. Any ideas on what to check or why it might be saving in current directory.

Comment: Are you sure the config is getting evaluated? Maybe you have a `.emacs` file and an `.emacs.d\init.el`?

Comment: Yes, config is evaluated and no .emacs.d\init.el. Even if I reload the setup.el it still doesn't take effect. It is like it ignores these settings. Not sure what the go is.

Comment: Bozhidar - I realized even if I turn auto-save-mode off in that buffer. I still get those files starting with .# so must be something else causing that. I'm not sure. Maybe temporary backup files?? I'm not sure. I have backup by copyting set to t so not sure if these are for that.

Comment: You should try the config when you've started emacs with `-q` - I guess something in your current config is amiss.

Comment: That was a good thought but no go with -q. Still puts these temporary files .#whatever.org until the autosave happens in which the #whatever# is stored in that folder.

Comment: Also realized that these files are symlinks .#temper1.py -> big@big-desktop.774:1341142158 to user@system but not really sure. This might be something to do with ubuntu or linux. It happens on both 10.04 and 12.04 with different versions of emacs. I have posted to the mailing list.

Comment: Found the answer has to do with locking the file. It's supposed to do that and has nothing to do with autosave or backup.